# SQL Param Data Validation

Tags: sql, validation, stored-procedures, ssms

I was wondering, is it possible to validate data in stored procs in a more specific manner than just the data type?  Let's say I have the following stored proc for SQL Server 2012 (Please critique as much as you'd like on anything, I'd love, and need, the feedback)

```
*USE [4YourSoulServerRev2]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
Alter Procedure [dbo].[Place_On_Hold_sp]
    @clientID numeric (5),
    @batchId numeric (18),
    @barcode varchar (50) = null

AS 
Begin
Use aswsaddressdata
update data set cancel = 'Y'
where clientid = @clientID and batchid = @batchId
where Barcode in 
(
@barcode
);
end*
```

Is there a way to make sure that the paramaters first match certain formats and checks before entering in.  If my job would allow me to create a front-end user-interface, I'd do the checks directly on the form but they want it in the stored proc itself since these will be ran directly (btw our dba quit last week so we have none right now other than the CTO and CIO acting as it temporarily).

Thank you

Comment: Do the checks as logic in the stored procedure.

Comment: t-sql supports if/else logic so you can check pretty much anything you want.  It also allows you to throw a custom error if your parameters don't pass muster.

Comment: Why are there two where clause?

Comment: What kind of fomat test you need? I mean, if the format doesn't match then the where clause will return no resuls anyway. Can you provide a specific example of the kind of test you have in mind?